# Remove S3 object after assign tag

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, lifecycle, amazon-glacier

I'd like to delete AWS S3 Object 30 days after assign tag. It seems to be easy when I tagged a new file during creation, but what if the file was created more than 30 days ago and I still want to be compliant  with retention policy (30 days) and do not delete it too early.

I was hoping that I could use transaction Lifecycle policy to the Glacier and then delete the file but it also based on creation date.

Is there another option without lambda usage?

```
{
    "Rules": [
        {
            "Status": "Enabled", 
            "NoncurrentVersionExpiration": {
                "NoncurrentDays": 31
            }, 
            "NoncurrentVersionTransitions": [
                {
                    "NoncurrentDays": 1, 
                    "StorageClass": "GLACIER"
                }
            ], 
            "Filter": {
                "Tag": {
                    "Value": "true", 
                    "Key": "toDelete"
                }
            }, 
            "Expiration": {
                "Days": 31
            }, 
            "Transitions": [
                {
                    "Days": 1, 
                    "StorageClass": "GLACIER"
                }
            ], 
            "ID": "delete-tagged-toDelete-after-31days"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no "out-of-the-box" solution for what you wish to do.

Amazon S3 Lifecycle Rules are based on **Creation Date**. Adding a tag to an object is not sufficient to "reset the clock" for a lifecycle rule.

Some ideas:

- You *might* be able to **copy the object** to itself and add a tag. This might should the Create Date on the object.
- You can create an **AWS Lambda function**, triggered on a regular schedule by an Amazon CloudWatch Events rule, that scans the bucket for objects and deletes them based on tag. The tag could contain a delete date that the Lambda function uses to determine whether the delete date has passed.